# Currency Conversion. Decimal becomes bigger value

Tags: php, math

So, some people here helped me in the past with currency conversion, works amazing. Unless its under a whole number.

```
1 = 0.023 (Using my rates)
0.01 = 2.30000000001 (something like that)
```

`0.01` will become a HUGE number.

```
function convert($to, $from, $value) {
    return ($value * $to) / $from;
};
```

Comment: What means `$from` and `$to` in the function?

Comment: 0.01 becomes 2.3, that's hardly a huge number, unless you mean it has more decimal points than what you want.

Comment: tbh even looking at the previous question I'm still not sure this makes sense - mathematically speaking. If 1 = 0.023 why does 0.01 = 2.3? 100 = 2.3, fine or even 43.47826 = 1 ... but 1/100th? I'm sure I'm not getting something here...

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Oh im using a json file with rates. $from (lets say  my cryptocurrency I wanna make for fun) 0.023 and $to is USD $1

Comment: @apokryfos It should be a really small decimal not what it comes out to be. I'm making a crypto currency as a project for my buds and I. and that is just so BIG compared to what it should be.

Comment: @CD001 Yes that make since, but I don't see how to make it a smaller decimal instead of it going bigger.

Comment: if it's just a formatting issue, `number_format($float, 2, '.', '')` ought to do it or the NumberFormatter class : http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: ... or are you referring to floating point precision (rounding errors when dealing with floating point calculations): http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: @CD001 0.01USD = 2.30FMC when I use that. I'll read the manual.

Comment: Oki but what's doing my noggin in is if `0.01USD = 2.30FMC` then 1 FMC does **not** equal 0.023 USD but 0.43478 USD (there being 230 FMCs to the Dollar right?) - I don't understand where that `1 = 0.023` is coming from.

Comment: @CD001 http://femicoin.cf/rate.json

Comment: @CD001 1USD = 0.023, 0.01USD = 2.3, 100USD = 2.3... I don't want hte 0.01USD to = 2.3

Comment: ^ that makes no sense mathematically; if `1D = 0.023F` then `100D = 2.3F` ... then `0.01D` **must** be `0.00023F` (not 2.3).

Comment: @CD001 but... thats how it coming out.
Here. Lemme pull the function I'm using

Comment: @CD001

            `function con($from, $to, $value) {
              $math = ($value * $to) / $from;
              return $math;
            };

  $result = con($total, $to, $from);

$total = "0.01";
$to = "0.023";
$from = "1";`

I see my error... I think. Lemme test it.

Comment: @CD001 

I'm an idiot :)

Comment: heh - just one of those things where it takes a new pair of eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was an idiot and did the function backwards.

I was doing $value, $to, $from instead of $from, $to, $value